# How to set initial zoom of bokeh box chart of pandas group with a large number of categories

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm plotting covid-19 data for countries grouped by World Bank regions using pandas and Bokeh.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

group = data.groupby(["region", "CountryName"])

index_cmap = factor_cmap(
    'region_CountryName', 
    palette=Spectral5, 
    factors=sorted(data.region.unique()), 
    end=1
)

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600, title="Confirmed cases per 100k people by country",
           x_range=group, toolbar_location="left")

p.vbar(x='region_CountryName', top='ConfirmedPer100k_max', width=1, source=group,
       line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

p.y_range.start = 0
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3.14159/2
p.xaxis.group_label_orientation = 3.14159/2
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

And I get a 
[image: cluttered graph like this one]

I would like to set some sort of initial zoom into the x-axis to get a more manageable image 
[image: like this one], which I got by manually zooming in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with the x_range parameter. In this example, the plot's x range would be the first 20 countries. You can adjust as needed. You might also have to mess around a bit to get the group_cn_list correct. It's hard to say without seeing your data. If you can post a df example for reproducibility, it would help.

```
group_cn_list = group["CountryName"].tolist()

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600, title="Confirmed cases per 100k people by country",
x_range=group_cn_list[0:20], toolbar_location="left")
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. Perhaps because the group is created by a key pair, "region", "CountryName". I tried ```group_cn_list = list(group.groups.keys())``` instead but I got a ```ValueError: Unrecognized range input: '[('Aggregates', 'Anguilla'), ('Aggregates', 'Caribbean Netherlands'), ...```

Comment: x_range is def the parameter, but you need to pass a flat list. Your example in the comment above looks like a list of tuples.